# SMBIOSAssetTag in Win32_SystemEnclosure is empty

Tags: wmi, wsh

Using the `Win32_SystemEnclosure` class and check the value of local machine AssetTag and Partnumber. Can anyone advise how to obtain the `Service Tag` of a local machine using one of the `Win32_System_XXX` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32_SystemEnclosure and Win32_ComputerSystemProduct both have properties SerialNumber and IdentifyingNumber respectively that have the same value i.e. Service Tag.